# If another team haven't done a requested task, are we supposed to mention it in every Daily Scrum as an Impediment until they do?

Tags: agile, scrum

Is it really necessary to mention the same impediment (blocking issue) in every daily standup, if the whole Scrum team already know about it because it's been mentioned at previous daily standups?

Comment: Is it an impediment, or dependency? Is there an time estimate for the dependency?

Answer (score 12):

Just the fact there is a dependency on task other team is doing right now seems weird to me. Usually, you don't want to add tasks into sprint if you are not even sure if you can finish it within a sprint, because you cannot know if the dependency will be completed. Usually, you want to postpone adding this task until it's dependency was finished.

On your comment of NEED to have this feature finished: You are not doing agile right. If it is so important, you should have added it into sprint (along with it's dependency) much earlier. And even if this requirement appeared suddenly, it is not a reason to add it into sprint right away. If your sprints are short, the wait of few weeks is not going to kill anyone. Of course the problem is different if bug in dependency exists for many sprints and still isn't fixed. In which case, there is some serious process problem and your product owner and scrum master should be looking into it ASAP. In general agile, bugs should have highest priority and should be fixed before any kind of features are added in sprint. I would send your scrum master to the other team and ask what kind of half-arsed agile are they doing.

Comment: OK, good point, but it is not always this simple. Two examples: (a) "We NEED this feature by the end of the sprint, so the dependency must be implemented by the other team simultaneously"; (b) a dependency is thought to be complete already, but actually has a serious bug, that means the story depending on it can't be considered done until that bug is fixed.

Comment: @RobinGreen See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

I do think it's worth mention every day; your CSM should be charged with removing roadblocks, but reality shows that they are often spread too thinly across an organization.

When an impediment is truly blocking progress on a task and there's no timeframe for a remedy, that can serve as an indicator for a PO to either re-evaluate priority of your blocked task or work with the other team to drag the blocked task into your team so that you can remove it yourself.

When it's time to retrospect the iteration/sprint, that blockage could be an example of things to improve at an organizational level.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. First time need to discuss this blocking issue, but second time it doesn't necessary. But when there are new information about this topic, it need to discuss all story again.

I think If there aren't any new information, news about this impediment, it doesn't necessary to mention in every daily standups.

---

During the Daily Srum the team members explain:

- What did I do yesterday that helped the Development Team
  meet the Sprint Goal?
- What will I do today to help the Development Team meet the Sprint Goal?
- Do I see any impediment that prevents me or the Development Team from meeting the
  Sprint Goal?

From [Scrum Guide.](https://www.scrum.org/Portals/0/Documents/Scrum%20Guides/2013/Scrum-Guide.pdf#zoom=100)